# Applying same operation over columns with same string within column names?

Tags: r

This may be a very simple question but I feel like I have two different answers that are helpful but are hard to put together. This is also my first question on StackOverflow so here goes:

I have a data frame that is measurements of a chemical process. There are column names like AirValve, PressureValve, OilLevel, PressureLevel etc.
The values in these columns are either NA or a whole number.

For Example:

```
AirValve <-c(rep(1,3),rep(2,5),rep(3,8),rep(4,4)) PressureLevel<-c(12,NA,NA,15,NA,NA,NA,NA,14,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,16,NA,NA,NA) df1<-data.frame(AirValve,PressureLevel)
```

I have to turn all the NAs to 0s, but only in certain columns with the word "Level" in the name.

If it was just df1$PressureLevel I could do:

```
df1$PressureLevel[is.na(df1$PressureLevel)] <- 0
```

But there are many other columns with "Level" in the name.

I also know grepl can be used as such:

```
grepl("Level", names(df1))
```

but don't know exactly what it does or how it can be used together with the previous line.

How would I turn NA values to 0 values in only columns that satisfy this grepl condition?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `contains()`selection helper here.

With dplyr, we can mutate `across()` columns that `contains()` the pattern "Level", and `replace()`these values with 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% mutate(across(contains("Level"), ~replace(.x, is.na(.x), 0)))
```

replace() is usually more general and can be used to replace different values. For NAs in particular, we can also use `coalesce()` or `replace_na`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% mutate(across(contains("Level"), ~coalesce(.x, 0)))

#OR

df1 %>% mutate(across(contains("Level"), replace_na, 0))
```

**output**

```
   AirValve PressureLevel
1         1            12
2         1             0
3         1             0
4         2            15
5         2             0
6         2             0
7         2             0
8         2             0
9         3            14
10        3             0
11        3             0
12        3             0
13        3             0
14        3             0
15        3             0
16        3             0
17        4            16
18        4             0
19        4             0
20        4             0
```

Comment: There's also `replace_na`: `mutate(across(contains("Level"), replace_na, 0))`

Comment: yes, you are right, thanks again, andrew_reece, for tunning up the answer a notch

Comment: Thank you for this! If instead of replacing NAs with 0s I wanted to do something else within those same columns (like copy values from previous row), would I just write something else in the "coalesce" or "replace" section?

Comment: With `across(selection_helper)` you can select columns with several different criteria (name matching with "contains", "starts_with", etc, logical indexing with "where", and so on). You can then perform any operation on the column with the `.fns` argument of across

Comment: An example: `df1 %>% mutate(across(contains('Level'), function(x) x+1))` will add 1 do all values in the selected columns

Comment: You are looking for the `fill()` function, as in `df1 %>% fill(contains("Level"))`

Comment: you can also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

We can use the same option

```
nm1 <- grepl("Level", names(df1))
df1[nm1][is.na(df1[nm1])] <- 0
```

---

If we want to replace the NA elements with previous non-NA

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(x1) %>%
     fill(x2)
```

Comment: Thank you!
If instead of replacing NAs with 0s, I wanted to do something described in this 
[link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-fill-the-na-values-from-above-row-values-in-an-r-data-frame)
Where I replace all NA values with the first previous non-NA value. The code in the link is :
df1$x2<-df1$x2[match(df1$x1,df1$x1)]
Would I just replace df1$x2 with df1[nm1]?

Comment: @user2499554 you can use `fill` asin the update